# Debug Blackberry Applications from Eclipse, App cannot be found on device or emulator

Tags: eclipse, debugging, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I was debugging blackberry apps from Eclipse. It works fine at the beginning but since some days ago, I could no longer get the app onto any emulator or device.

The packaging and signing shows NO error. After it displays the "debugger attaching..." screen, I could not find the app anywhere on the emulator or device. I have tried to reinstall the eclipse and JDEs a few times. One observation is that it had about 280 files to sign. Without any changes in the code now it has 540 files to sign.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't get installed? Are you looking in the correct app folder?

Comment: 1.first of all check the titlt of the app in BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml file.

Comment: 2.for OS 5 and below the app will saved in downlods folder

Comment: Hi Raj thanks for the reply. I am using OS5 devices. I have checked every sigle folder on the device and emulator. I have also tried to build the project with a Hudson build server and download the app Over The Air and it actually works.

Comment: If you've already tried reinstalling the toolset, maybe it's your project directory that's corrupted.  Having 280 files to sign, and then having that nearly double sounds like somehow, a bunch of extra files got copied into your project folder.  Try going through your project directories and subdirectories, and prune them all (just in windows explorer).  Then, clean, rebuild, and try to run on the simulator again.

Comment: Thanks Nate. Finally I resolved the issue by reducing the image file sizes of my projet. And it reduced the number of  files to 330. I am not sure whether there is some UPPER-Limit to the number of cod files that can be supported when debugging with elispe?